# How does a firewall know not to block response packets?

Tags: networking, firewall

When a firewall lets packets sent in response to a request pass, how does it know that certain packets are associated with a request sent from inside the network?
Does it keep track of TCP connections or does it use some kind of a session?

For example, my browser makes a request that goes through the firewall in the router and the firewall knows to let response packets through. On the other hand, if someone from outside makes a request to any computer inside my network, they will get blocked.

Answer (score 5):

For TCP, it does keep track of connections.

For UDP, each outgoing packet creates (or refreshes) a temporary rule to forward inbound packets back to the local source of the outgoing UDP packet.

Comment: How long do firewalls typically wait before closing the port?

Comment: @QuaternionsRock you can check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524295/how-long-does-conntrack-remember-a-connection